# Update Cell value From another Cell value in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to Update a cell value according to another cell in datagrid.
for example i have a quantity column and a total price column
when i change the quantity i trigger a CellEditEnding event, which takes the quantity and do some logic operation and save it in the totalpricecolumn of the row itself.
after that, the totalprice not changing, only after i click the totalprice cell for editing mode, than i see the result.

my question is: how can see the result right after the CellEditEnding completes?

here's my xaml:

```
<DataGrid Name="itemsInSheet" CanUserAddRows="False" PreviewTextInput="PreviewQuantityChanged" CellEditEnding="itemsInSheet_CellEditEnding" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsInPricingSheet , Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Panel.ZIndex="-1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="סה''כ מחיר" Binding="{Binding TotalPrice, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="כמות" Binding="{Binding Quantity, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="שם פריט" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding ItemID, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ItemIDToItemName}}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="שם קבוצה" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding GroupID, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource GroupIDToGroupName}}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Here's my CellEditEnding  event:

```
private void itemsInSheet_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit)
        {
            var column = e.Column as DataGridBoundColumn;
            if (column != null)
            {                    
                var bindingPath = (column.Binding as Binding).Path.Path;
                if (bindingPath == "Quantity")
                {                       
                    int rowIndex = e.Row.GetIndex();
                    var el = e.EditingElement as TextBox;
                    m_engine.UpdateTotalPrice(rowIndex);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And here's the UpdateTotalPrice (for now i keep it simple and the total price equal to the Quantity):

```
internal void UpdateTotalPrice(int rowIndex)
    {
       sp_GetItemsInPricingSheets_Result data = m_PricingSheetManagerViewModel.ItemsInPricingSheet.ElementAt(rowIndex);
       data.TotalPrice = (decimal)data.Quantity;
    }
```

ADDITIONAL INFO:
here's the viewmodel i'm using:

```
 public class PricingSheetManagerViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<sp_GetGroups_Result> m_groups;
    public ObservableCollection<sp_GetGroups_Result> Groups
    {
        get { return m_groups; }
        set
        {
            m_groups = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Groups");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<sp_GetItems_Result> m_items;
    public ObservableCollection<sp_GetItems_Result> Items
    {
        get { return m_items; }
        set
        {
            m_items = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Items");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<sp_GetItemsInPricingSheets_Result> m_itemsInPricingSheet;
    public ObservableCollection<sp_GetItemsInPricingSheets_Result> ItemsInPricingSheet
    {
        get { return m_itemsInPricingSheet; }
        set
        {
            m_itemsInPricingSheet = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ItemsInPricingSheet");
        }
    }

    private sp_GetPricingSheets_Result m_pricingSheet = new sp_GetPricingSheets_Result();
    public sp_GetPricingSheets_Result PricingSheet
    {
        get { return m_pricingSheet; }
        set
        {
            m_pricingSheet = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("PricingSheet");
        }
    }

    #region "PropertyChanged Event"
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion   
}
```

Comment: Can you change the Quantity UpdateSourceTrigger to LostFocus? If yes, You can do this in Quantity property setter. Just set the Total price to new value there. You don't need these methods at all. You can do that in your ViewModel.

Comment: how can i do it? the logic of the total price is not in  the view (i gave a simple example for setting the totalprice, the new total price includes multipcations and other logic operations, so setting value inside xaml will not work for me)

Comment: Could you please post your ViewModel class (Where TotalPrice and Quantity properties are stored.)?

Comment: the view model i'm using is in the question . sp_GetItemsInPricingSheets_Result  class is from entityframework and the TotalPrice and Quantity are properties, this class not implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 0):

I managed to see the item after i update it by focus the data grid, set the current cell to the required cell, and set begin edit
this i added inside the itemsInSheet_CellEditEnding event
here's the code after update:

```
private void itemsInSheet_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit)
        {
            var column = e.Column as DataGridBoundColumn;
            if (column != null)
            {                    
                var bindingPath = (column.Binding as Binding).Path.Path;
                if (bindingPath == "Quantity")
                {                       
                    int rowIndex = e.Row.GetIndex();
                    var el = e.EditingElement as TextBox;
                    m_engine.UpdateTotalPrice(rowIndex);
                    itemsInSheet.Focus();
                    itemsInSheet.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(itemsInSheet.Items[rowIndex], itemsInSheet.Columns[0]);
                    itemsInSheet.BeginEdit();                  
                }
            }
        }
    }
```